# How do I debug Omniauth and Rack applications?

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems, rack

I'm trying to authenticate over eBay using Rack + omniauth (in fact - omniauth-ebay). I have a correct configuration (instead of "111", "222"... there are real values):

```
#config.rb
 use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :ebay, "111", "222", "333", "4444", "0", "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi" 
 end
```

When I go to l`ocalhost:9292/auth/ebay`, I receive an error of:

```
    NoMethodError at /auth/ebay
    undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    file: ebay_api.rb location: generate_session_id line: 21

 #....
omniauth.error  - <NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
omniauth.error.strategy - #<OmniAuth::Strategies::Ebay>
omniauth.error.type - "Failed to retrieve session id from ebay"
omniauth.strategy - <OmniAuth::Strategies::Ebay>
```

What I want to know is how to debug that? Especially the path of `localhost:9292/auth/ebay` since I don't have it defined in my application because Omniauth *embeds* it automatically.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omniauth ebay uses pure XML version of eBay API as opposed to SOAP version. Your last configuration value should be

```
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll
```

not

```
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi
```

As a side note, based on your error, [ebay_api.rb](https://github.com/TheGiftsProject/omniauth-ebay/blob/c7fefe7eed86120634e8e9f480b5951e7e36f0d6/lib/ebay_api.rb), you seem to have a earlier version of omniauth-ebay gem installed. In the [latest version](https://github.com/TheGiftsProject/omniauth-ebay/blob/master/lib/ebay_api.rb), there is more error checking and should give you more details.

Comment: That's right, the url is now correct. But I use the latest version, I just installed it.

Comment: But now it redirects me to production signIn url which is https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll. How do make it to use sandbox url - https://signin.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll  ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this value is hard-coded in [ebay_api.rb](https://github.com/TheGiftsProject/omniauth-ebay/blob/master/lib/ebay_api.rb). You can change this locally `EBAY_LOGIN_URL`

Comment: I tried to set `EbayAPI::EBAY_LOGIN_URL = "signin.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll` right after `use OmniAuth::Builder do...` in config.rb. And it redirected me to `http://localhost:9292/auth/signin.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?....` which was wrong. Should I call `EbayAPI::EBAY_LOGIN_URL =..`  in another place? What are your ideas?

Comment: Looks like mini-Markdown editor here stripped away https://. Set EBAY_LOGIN_URL to `https://signin.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll`

Comment: Seems very logical but it still does not work, it uses the production url.

Comment: I think this time, its eBay doing the redirect. In your [application settings](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/account/appsettings/), under Manage your RuNames, update Accept and Reject redirect URL appropriately. This defaults to production urls creating this confusion.

Comment: I mean it's still redirecting to production url for some reason and telling that auth-on was cancelled. If I manually change the url to sandbox url, it's working well and it's authenticating me.